# How to use the Site.css in my child windows?

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm using the **Visual Studio 2012** asp.net web application template. The styles in the **Site.css** class -which is in the existing template- are applied in the master page and the content pages well. However, I created a few popup pages and added the references to the CssClasses that exist in the Site.css but these aren't working.

How can I use the Site.css styles in my child windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each separate page (not a content page) has to have a link to each CSS or Javascript Files. These pages are not related to each other. So each page has its own CSS and Javascript Files. Thus, each page that uses Site.css must include a link to this file.

Hope the answer is usefull.